# Android Unicode Character in TextView After Setting TypeFace

Tags: android, unicode, textview

I am attempting to use a unicode character with a custom font within a `TextView`. I have a string:

```
<string name="profile_hint_1">Edit your profile &#8594;</string>
```

I create the `TypeFace` and set the `TextView`

```
Typeface fontMarkerFelt = Typeface.createFromAsset( context.getAssets(), "fonts/MarkerFeltThin-Regular.ttf" );
tvHint1.setTypeface(fontMarkerFelt);
tvHint1.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.profile_hint_1));
```

The `TextView` then has the string in the correct font minus the → character. If I comment out the line

```
tvHint1.setTypeface(fontMarkerFelt);
```

Then the → character appears properly. Is there a way to display the unicode character with the custom font?

Comment: Maybe the font doesn't support unicode characters?

Comment: That's probably was it is. I wasn't 100% sure if different fonts support unicode characters.